# Getting error: ValueError: unsupported format character: '('

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I have the below function for generating an SQL query dynamically to insert a pandas dataframe in postgres using psycopg2. I'll be using this function to insert multiple dataframes which might not have all the columns in the database hence why I'm not using pandas.to_sql().
I keep getting the error `ValueError: unsupported format character: '('` and can't figure what is causing it.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
def execute_values(conn, df, schema, table):
    """
    Using psycopg2.extras.execute_values() to insert the dataframe
    """
    
    # Create a tuple of dicts from the dataframe values
    dicts = tuple(df.to_dict('records'))

    columns = sql.SQL(',').join(map(sql.Identifier, list(df.columns)))
    values = sql.SQL(',').join(map(sql.Placeholder, list(df.columns)))

    # SQL query to execute
    query = sql.SQL('INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES ({})').format(
        sql.Identifier(schema, table),
        columns,
        values
    )
    
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    try:
        extras.execute_values(cursor, query, dicts)
        conn.commit()
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print("Error: %s" % error)
        conn.rollback()
        cursor.close()
        raise

    print("execute_values() done")
    cursor.close()
```

Comment: If I am following this `INSERT INTO {} ({}) ..` should be `INSERT INTO {}.{} ({})...` . And the `sql.Identifier() ` needs to be split into one for the schema and one for the table.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver as per psycopg documentation (https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html): 
Multiple strings can be passed to the object to represent a qualified name, i.e. a dot-separated sequence of identifiers.

Example:
```query = sql.SQL("select {} from {}").format(
sql.Identifier("table", "field"),
sql.Identifier("schema", "table"))
print(query.as_string(conn))
select "table"."field" from "schema"."table"```

Comment: What version of  `psycopg2` are you using?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver psycopg2 v2.8.6

Comment: Well that is new enough. Then the next suspects are `columns` and `values`. Try a `print()` on both to see what is actually there. It would not hurt to also see what is being passed in for `schema` and `table`.

Comment: Well it all looks normal (I think!). Here is the query (print(query.as_string(cursor)): `INSERT INTO "diamondprincess"."operationaldata" ("current_datetime", "1P_ALS", "1S_ALS", "2P_ALS", "2S_ALS", "3P_ALS") 
VALUES (%(current_datetime)s, %(1P_ALS)s, %(1S_ALS)s, %(2P_ALS)s, %(2S_ALS)s, %(3P_ALS)s, %(3S_ALS)s)`

Comment: Oops, I missed the part where you are using `execute_values`.  You need to use the form as shown here [Execute Values](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html?highlight=execute_values#psycopg2.extras.execute_values). Basically `VALUES %s`. No need to build the `sql.Placeholder` portion.

Comment: So what would you use with sql.placeholder instead? I'm using placeholder as not all dataframes will have the same number of colums/ columns order. Does values %s take care of this?

Comment: See example in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to do make dynamic SQL using `execute_values`:

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import execute_values
from psycopg2 import sql

con = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test host=localhost user=aklaver")
cur = con.cursor()

columns = sql.SQL(',').join(map(sql.Identifier, ['id', 'cond', 'animal']))

data_dict = [{"id": 20, "cond": "fair", "animal": "fish"}, {"id": 30, "cond": "poor", "animal": "fish"}, {"id": 40, "cond": "great", "animal": "fish"}]


values = sql.SQL(',').join(map(sql.Placeholder, ['id', 'cond', 'animal']))
# Since you are using a dict you need to provide a template for 
# execute_values
values_template = sql.SQL('(') + values + sql.SQL(')')

print(values_template.as_string(con))                                                                                                                                     (%(id)s,%(cond)s,%(animal)s)


insert_sql = sql.SQL("INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES %s").format(sql.Identifier("animals"), columns)

print(insert_sql.as_string(con))
INSERT INTO "animals" ("id","cond","animal") VALUES %s

execute_values(cur, insert_sql, data_dict, template=values_template)
con.commit()

 select * from animals ;
 id | cond  | animal 
----+-------+--------
 20 | fair  | fish
 30 | poor  | fish
 40 | great | fish
```

Comment: Thank you! That works great. Just out of curiosity, what would you use to execute the query I had instead of execute_values? Because I got my query from the psycopg2 [docs](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html#psycopg2.sql.Placeholder).

Comment: It really depends on how much data you are working with. You also have the option of using `execute_batch` which would use the your query as originally built, but batches the the statements by some `page_size`.  If you are dealing with large amounts of data for inserting into a table then [COPY](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#copy) is the best performing option.